# Where can I get the fmt binary for MSYS/MinGW?

Tags: git, bash, msys

I am using virtualenvwrapper with Git Bash (msysGit).

Mostly this works fine, but the **lsvirtualenv** command relies on the **fmt** unix command, which is not currently on my path.

I would like to add only **fmt.exe** to my Git Bash **bin** if possible, in the interests of doing a minimal install.

For the life of me I cannot find a standalone **fmt** - it looks like it used to be a part of MSYS coreutils, but is now no longer present.

Please could someone give me some pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: I've been digging around in SF here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.

In the end, one of the MinGW users on their mailing list (Eli Zaretskii) pointed me in the right direction.

**fmt.exe** now lives here in Sourceforge:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/coreutils/coreutils-5.97-3/coreutils-5.97-3-msys-1.0.13-ext.tar.lzma/download

It needs two DLL libraries (libintl and libiconv) which get copied across into the git bash bin directory too. They live here in Sourceforge:

**libintl**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/gettext/gettext-0.18.1.1-1/libintl-0.18.1.1-1-msys-1.0.17-dll-8.tar.lzma/download

**libiconv**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/libiconv/libiconv-1.14-1/libiconv-1.14-1-msys-1.0.17-dll-2.tar.lzma/download

Now, this little lot will get fmt.exe working in your git bash, but lsvirtualenv still does not work properly... but I think that is a virtualenvwrapper problem now!

Comment: Quick update - **virtualenvwrapper** works fine for most purposes now.. you do need to set your MSYS_HOME environment variable to your git-bash installation directory (the one above bin).

Note that **lsvirtualenv** and **cpvirtualenv** do not work properly due to Windows path & path-separator confusion. I will log a bug ticket for these once I get a chance to investigate properly.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an exe, but, I have a simple(ish) `fmt` replacement written in Python, by me and Donn Seeley.  It's Unix/Linux-centric (makes some assumptions about `errno`) but should be easily adapted.

Available via [link](http://web.torek.net/torek/git/fmt.py.txt); strip the .txt extension to turn it into a `.py` file.

Comment: Cheers for this suggestion!